# Finding the "middle element" from a vector in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Simple newbie question in Clojure...

If I have an odd number of elements in a Clojure vector, how can I extract the "middle" value?  I've been looking at this for a while and can't work out how to do it!

Some examples:

- `(middle-value [0])` should return `[0]`
- `(middle-value [0 1 2])` should return `[1]`
- `(middle-value [0 1 :abc 3 4])` should return `[:abc]`
- `(middle-value [0 1 2 "test" 4 5 6])` should return `["test"]`

Comment: What should it return when there are an even number of elements?

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler - won't ever happen, so I'm not worried about it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about calculating the middle index and accessing by it?

```
(defn middle-value [vect]
  (when-not (empty? vect)
    (vect (quot (count vect) 2))))
```

Comment: You can use `(quot (count vect) 2)`

Answer (score 5):

A somewhat inefficient but fun implementation (works with sequence abstraction instead of concrete vector):

```
(defn middle [[fst & rst]]
  (if-not rst fst
    (recur (butlast rst))))
```

Returns `nil` in case of even amount of elements.

Less fun but more efficient:

```
(nth v (quot (count v) 2))
```

where `v` is the vector.

Comment: The destructuring will have `rst` be nil when there are no more elements, so you don't need to `seq` it.

Answer (score 1):

Get the number of items in the vector, halve it, floor the result and get the item at that index. Assuming a vector `v`:

```
(get v (floor (/ (count v) 2)))
```

Unfortunately `floor` isn't in `clojure.core`, you'll need to pull in another library for that or go directly to `java.lang.Math.floor`.

This code, of course, doesn't do anything about even-counted vectors, but I'm assuming you can handle those already.

Comment: see bereal's answer, with quot in clojure.core you don't need floor.

Comment: That's rather cunning. Half this business is knowing what's in the giant library...

Comment: Also see bereals answer that you don't need `get`